# Is there a C# equivalent of PHP's array_key_exists?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Does C# have any equivalent of PHP's [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function?

For example, I have this PHP code:

```
$array = array();
$array[5] = 4;
$array[7] = 8;
if (array_key_exists($array, 2))
    echo $array[2];
```

How would I turn this into C#?

Comment: This is a bad question - array means different things in each language - from a c# perspective a php associative array is a dictionary - in c# arrays don't have keys they only have an sequential index

Comment: @web_bod donchano of Dictionary<TKey, TValue> in the System.Collections.Generic namespace??

Comment: yes - but he says "I have an `array` and I want know if contains value on selected key" - `arrays` don't have `keys` donchno!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but dynamic arrays like PHP are not supported in C#. What you can do it create a [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and add using [.Add(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict.Add(5, 4);
dict.Add(7, 8);
if (dict.ContainsKey(5))
{
    // [5, int] exists
    int outval = dict[5];
    // outval now contains 4
}
```

Comment: Dynamic arrays are supported; they're called Lists and they can be referenced by key just like PHP arrays.

Comment: I know I’m _8 years_ late to reply to this comment, but my understanding is that PHP arrays are _sparse_. Meaning, you can have `$arr[0]` and `$arr[2]` defined, but `$arr[1]` undefined.

Answer (score 7):

An array in C# has a fixed size, so you would declare an array of 8 integers

```
int[] array = new int[8];
```

You then only need to check the length

```
if(array.Length > 2)
{
    Debug.WriteLine( array[2] );
}
```

That's fine for value types, but if you have an array of reference types, e.g.

```
Person[] array = new Person[8];
```

then you'll need to check for null as in

```
if(array.Length > 2 && array[2] != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine( array[2].ToString() );
}
```

Comment: or use Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Comment: This answer looks the most informative. But since PHP probably has a different idea about what an array is, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is a better approach. In array you only have indices, therefore you will have as many "keys" as the size of the array is. In Dictionary, you only have as many key-value pairs as you add there.

Answer (score 4):

In C# when you declare a new array, you have to provide it a size for memory allocation. If you're creating an array of `int`, values are pre-populated at instantiation, so the keys will always exist.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine(array[0]); //outputs 0.
```

If you want a dynamically sized array, you can use a `List`.

```
List<int> array = new List<int>
array.push(0);

if (array.Length > 5)
   Console.WriteLine(array[5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ContainsKey

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"mac", 1000},
    {"windows", 500}
};

// Use ContainsKey method.
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("mac") == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary["mac"]); // <-- Is executed
}

// Use ContainsKey method on another string.
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("acorn"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(false); // <-- Not hit
}
```

Comment: +1, though I think the important point is that he/she wants a Dictionary rather than an Array.

Comment: Just reading about php array which is an ordered map, not an array or dictionary.  I'm not sure there's an equivalent in C# unless it's a SortedDictionary.